# Adding table row scrolls to top

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have a table in a bootstrap container. If it has more rows than the height of the window and I scroll down and add a row, the window automatically scrolls me to the top of the window.

The table is the full size of the container.

How can I prevent it from scrolling to the top?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information to the world. So what is the question/problem ?

Comment: Either the link's href that add the row contains a `#` or you need to add logic and set the scrollTop to the scrollHeight. I can't say anything more useful without any code.

Comment: sorry forgot to say I don't want that behavior to happen Dave. Mouser, it was a # in there, did not notice it and did not think it could be that since I never tested it until I added bootstrap so my mind just jumped to it, if you want, put that as an answer and I validate